# External HDD Plugged into SATA shows uninitialized

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, sata

I checked my Seagate external drive, or tried to, but it just wouldn't open up in Windows Explorer. (It had been plugged into the PC's USB for months, but I had not bothered to access it in this period...previously it had been working fine)

Since I intended to plug it into the computer itself instead of hogging the USB anyway, I opened up the shell and found two Seagate/Samsung HDDs inside. I tried connecting each of these to my PC via SATA, but they didn't work - they wouldn't show up in Windows Explorer. When I run the Windows Partition Manager, I do see the drive, with a 33% of the drive showing as healthy and remaining as unallocated. I reckon I could merge the two partitions and initialize the drive(s), but that would mean losing the data.

Any suggestions as to how I could retrieve the data I have on these drives?

About cross-posting: I originally posted this at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and was directed here.

Comment: Your external drive was likely using a RAID configuration based on the fact there was two disks contained in the enclosure.  If you care about the data on the drive I would send to a data recovery company, since the RAID configuration complicates matters, well beyond the typical tools that are normally suggested by this community.  Many of the tools used by data recovery companies are not typically accessible to the pubic.